# SCSS change variable depending on parent class?

Tags: sass

I have this *problem*, in my work we have a base project that contains thousands of lines of scss codes and several variables. When this base is needed just for a website all is ok, the development goes fast. I can change the `$generalColor` variable(s) and the correct color is applied.

The problem comes when somewhere, in the same project, a new set of Colors (variables) are needed (microsite). Then usually one need to search every place where `$generalColor` is used and add something like:

```
$generalColor_SOMETHING: #453543;
.newExtraSetOfColor & {
    background: $generalColor_SOMETHING;
}
```

And that for each variable * each new set of colors. If there are a lot of microsites/color sets it is a nightmare.

Is there a better way to this? (javascript like?)

Answer (score 6):

It works with the ***!global*** flag ([SASS documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variables_)).

```
$theme-color: black;

.my-red-theme {
    $theme-color: red !global;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this with a mixin:

```sass
$colors: (
  // Default color set
  default: (
    red: #ff0000,
    green: #ff0000,
    blue: #ff0000
  ),
  // Pastel color set
  pastel: (
    red: #ff6961,
    green: #77dd77,
    blue: #aec6cf
  )
);

@mixin color($color) {
  color: map-get(map-get($colors, default), $color);  

  .colors--pastel & {
    color: map-get(map-get($colors, pastel), $color);  
  }
}

h1 {
  @include color(red);
}
```

Output:

```css
h1 {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.colors--pastel h1 {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: So I should do a mixin for every property that uses that color. `color`, `background`, `border` and so on.

Comment: @distante I'm afraid so. There are no dynamic variables in Sass.